# Can I have multiple rel="alternate" tags for a webpage?

Tags: html, seo, canonical-link

In My site I have used `rel="alternate"` for RSS as follows

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS 2.0" href="http://www.mydomain.com/rss" />
```

Now I want to add another `rel="alternate"` tag for the mobile site as

```
<link rel="alternate" media="handheld" href="http://m.mydomain.com" />
```

Is there any issue to use multiple `rel="alternate"` tags in a page or no any effect to the SEO?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's no problem, quite the contrary, it's even encouraged.

E.g. to link to several translations of a page; see the example in [HTML 4.01: Links and search engines](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.3.3). Or to link to several different feeds; see the example in [HTML5: Link type "`alternate`"](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#rel-alternate). Or to link to several different (= alternative) stylesheets.

Answer (score 3):

There soesn't seem to be any problem using multiple instances according to this page:

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=189077